# How to drop the duplicate node from input xml using xquery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Below are the Xml input in xquery, i want to drop the duplicate element

```
    let $doc := <a>
        <b>
            <b1/>
        </b>
        <c>
            <c1/>
            <c1/>
        </c>
        <b>
            <b1/>
        </b>
        <d>
            <d1>
                <d11/>     
                <d11/>
            </d1>
        </d>
    </a>

return distinct-values($doc)
```

expected output: my expected output is below means drop the duplicate node from input

```
<a>
    <b>
        <b1/>
    </b>
    <c>
        <c1/>
    </c>
    <d>
        <d1>
            <d11/>
        </d1>
    </d>
</a>
```

Thanks..

Comment: Please reply anyone above the question

Comment: @Ansari, you do not have `duplicate node`, it's the `xml` that is **wrong**!

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you define when a node is a duplicate of another? distinct-values works on sequences of atomic values so you could use it to eliminate duplicates from a sequence of number or strings or dates. For nodes, you could group by the serialization and recurse, if that is what you want: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuPrX/2

Answer (score 1):

The function `distinct-values` creates a sequence of distinct atomic values like strings, numbers, dates. To identify and eliminate duplicate nodes, we first need to understand how you define that a node is a duplicate of another, whether that is based solely on the child element structure or the values as well.

You also seem to want to eliminate duplicates recursively, so to give you an example that uses a recursive function that groups all children by the result of calling the `serialize` function in XQuery 3 here is a sample:

```
declare function local:eliminate-duplicates($element as element())
{
    element { $element => node-name() }
    {
        for $child at $child-pos in $element/*
        group by $xml := serialize($child)
        order by head($child-pos)
        return
            $child => head() => local:eliminate-duplicates()
    }
};

let $a := <a>
        <b>
            <b1/>
        </b>
        <c>
            <c1/>
            <c1/>
        </c>
        <b>
            <b1/>
        </b>
        <d>
            <d1>
                <d11/>     
                <d11/>
            </d1>
        </d>
    </a>
return 
    local:eliminate-duplicates($a)
```

Result at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuPrX/2 is

```
<a>
   <b>
      <b1/>
   </b>
   <c>
      <c1/>
   </c>
   <d>
      <d1>
         <d11/>
      </d1>
   </d>
</a>
```